# Rails 5.1 Configuring Built-in System Tests with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

After watching a [RailsConf video on ActionDispatch::systemTestCase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSn4B8orX70), I was excited to incorporate it into my current app.  Currently our test suite setup uses the following:

- [rspec](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec)
- [factory_girl](https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl)
- [capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara) `# for feature specs`
- [database_cleaner](https://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner) `# for feature specs, mostly for testing js`
- [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) `# for feature specs`
- [capybara-webkit](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara') `# for feature specs`

It was difficult to get the configuration working for our current setup, but we eventually got it working, thanks largely to an article by Avdi Grimm titled: [Configuring database_cleaner with Rails, RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/).

My hope was to use the built-in system tests of rails released in rails `5.1`. Since rails now has system testing built in: all I would need to worry about configuring is the following:

- `rspec`
- `factory_girl`

And that is it because `ActionDispatch::systemTestCase` takes care of `capybara`, `database_cleaner`, and it is already configured for the `selenium` driver.

For example: currently my `feature specs` are written like so (Capybara within the context of RSpec):

```
#spec/features/blogs/creating_blogs_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Logged in User can create a blog" do
  before do
    create(:logged_in_user)
  end

  scenario "successfully", js: true do
    ...
  end
end
```

So this is what a typical integration/feature/system spec might look like for a test suite configured with `rspec`, `database_cleaner`, `factory_girl`, and `capybara`.  I would like to convert it over to using `ActionDispatch::systemTestCase`.

However: I would like to use `ActionDispatch::systemTestCase` within the context of `RSpec`.

The RailsConf video above shows how ActionDispatch::systemTestCase works within the context of rails' default test suite layout (ex: [minitest](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest') with tests located in a `test` directory), but it did not discuss how to use ActionDispatch::systemTestCase within the context of RSpec.

I could not find any resources on making rails' built-in system tests configurable with RSpec, including within the [system testing section of the rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update October 2017:

Rspec-rails 3.7 is now fully compatible with system tests.

Basically, this is all you have to add to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end
end
```

https://medium.com/table-xi/a-quick-guide-to-rails-system-tests-in-rspec-b6e9e8a8b5f6

Answer (score 4):

According to the RailsConf Talk: [Teaching RSpec to Play nice with Rails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyPfrK1y1nc&feature=youtu.be&t=3m22s), as of `rspec-rails 3.6.0` it is *not* compatible with rails' system test integration.

It does appear that compatibility is being worked on via [this pull request](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/1813).